# Is there a difference between type signatures a -> b -> a and c -> a -> c?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

This question is a theoretical question about Haskell functions which can take arguments of any type. Is there a difference between the way functions with the type signatures of

```
a -> b -> a
```

and

```
c -> a -> c
```

are instantiated?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, you simply changed the name of the type *variables*. As long as you do not rename a variable to another variable (such that there is a name clash), there is no problem.

Comment: Depends on whether/how the type variables are bound elsewhere.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no difference. Since `a`, `b` and `c` start with a *lowercase*, these are *variables*. You can rename variables, and this remains the same, as long as two (or more) variables do not "*clash*".

Such clashes can happen if you rename a variable such that it has the same name as another variable, or when you rename two (or more) variables to the same new name. If you would rename the variable `a` for example to `b` in your first code fragment, then we would get `b -> b -> b`, but that is not the same, since then we enforce that the first and second parameter are of the same type. Whereas in your type signature, we have the freedom to pick two types that can be the same, but that is *not* necessary.

Answer (score 16):

Nope. Think of `a -> b -> a` as `This Type -> Another Type -> This Type`. Then both of them fit given pattern. However, something like `a -> b -> c` wont fit: `This Type -> That Type -> Yet Another Type` is (generally) different; except the edge case when `c = a`, which yields the pattern you're interested in.